# Spring Security CAS implementation in web service

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

Our team has been tasked with securing a web service somehow, now we have other web application that are secured with SpringSecurity CAS, and we were thinking that it would work to secure the web service with this as well. The thought being that if the user signs into one of the web applications through the CAS server, when the web service is called it will see that that user is already authenticated and allow them to utilize it. We aren't really sure if this is the correct way of doing this as there was a lot of talk about using HMAC or Oauth 2.0, but thought of CAS because that is what everything else is using.

Here is what I have so far after following this tutorial:

http://www.oudmaijer.com/2009/12/28/spring-3-spring-security-3-cas-3-3-4-integration/

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="2.5">
<display-name>webservice</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Start Spring CAS integration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- End Spring CAS integration -->
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<!--
    Enable security, let the casAuthenticationEntryPoint handle all intercepted urls.
    The CAS_FILTER needs to be in the right position within the filter chain.
-->
<security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"></security:intercept-url>
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter"></security:custom-filter>
</security:http>

<!--
    Required for the casProcessingFilter, so define it explicitly set and
    specify an Id Even though the authenticationManager is created by
    default when namespace based config is used.
-->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!--
    This section is used to configure CAS. The service is the
    actual redirect that will be triggered after the CAS login sequence.
-->
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/service/j_spring_cas_security_check"></property>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"></property>
</bean> 

    <!--
    The CAS filter handles the redirect from the CAS server and starts the ticket validation.
-->
<bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></property>
</bean>

<!--
    The entryPoint intercepts all the CAS authentication requests.
    It redirects to the CAS loginUrl for the CAS login page.
-->
<bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value=""></property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
</bean>

<!--
    Handles the CAS ticket processing.
 -->
<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"></property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value=""></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="cas"></property>
</bean>

<!--
    The users available for this application.
-->
<security:user-service id="userService">
    <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"></security:user>
</security:user-service>
```

Not sure what is missing or what's going on, but when I start up my tomcat server in eclipse, I get an error such as:

```
ERROR 2012-04-25 09:24:33 Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertyTypeDescriptor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
... 29 more
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertyTypeDescriptor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
... 29 more
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/bannernotifications] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Apr 25, 2012 9:24:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 855 ms
```

I'm sorry this is so long, but I just wanted to put as much out there as possible.

As @smp7d pointed out CAS might not be the best case for this. I found this,

[Securing REST and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141008/securing-rest-and-json)

which is exactly what this web service is, RESTful and serving up JSON, it is going to be hosted internally and only accessible internally. Now I guess the question has moved from using CAS, to what should we go with, what is the standard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are asking for reference material...

I can tell you that I doubt this exists at this time, when I performed a similar integration I had to go through the code to truly understand how to set it up properly for our environment. (Since it is all open source, this should not be an issue for you.) We then created internal documentation based on what we learned. This is going to be one of those cases where you need to refrain from trying to piece together a working implementation from existing configuration. Someone needs to fully understand what is actually happening.

As far as a web service that participates in CAS authentication, you would need to implement something like a Restlet:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API

I suggest that you evaluate your system thoroughly to decide if it really needs such a solution. If your "web service" calls are coming from a browser, CAS will handle it through the normal setup (though you will have to get creative to handle unauthenticated cases as you would not be redirecting to a login page).